# MySQL JSON aggregatable functions

Tags: mysql, json

MySQL since version 5.7 has some fundamental JSON support, however I've been looking through the documentation but couldn't find anything JSON aggregatable functions.

Are there any JSON aggregate functions in MySQL 5.7+?

For example if you have query:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM given_names GROUP BY id
```

You'd get a result like:

```
id | name
1  | Jon,Smith
2  | Hubert,Blaine,Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff
....
```

Is there an equivalent way to get a JSON array with?

My concern is with properly escaping strings because when you use `GROUP_CONCAT` if the string contains the separator it is near impossible to differentiate the parts afterwards.

Comment: The JSON functions seem so antithetical to the idea of relational data, I just can't figure out why they're there. What's wrong with spitting sql out to json_encode?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not arguing for JSON functions in a relational database, although I think MySQL is just trying to invade the NoSQL landscape by becoming "relational and then some" but I'm just saying, since JSON is already in there, why not JSON aggregation. The reason I ask is that I could eliminate a lot of rows with replicated data if such a thing existed (in this example it would just be `id` but there could be more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MySQL 5.7.22 it is possible using either [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) and [`JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg). Examples taken from the documentation:

#### JSON_ARRAYAGG

```
mysql> SELECT o_id, attribute, value FROM t3;
+------+-----------+--------+
| o_id | attribute | value  |
+------+-----------+--------+
|    2 | color     | red    |
|    2 | fabric    | silk   |
|    3 | color     | green  |
|    3 | shape     | square |
+------+-----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT o_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(attribute) AS attributes 
       FROM t3 GROUP BY o_id;
+------+---------------------+
| o_id | attributes          |
+------+---------------------+
|    2 | ["color", "fabric"] |
|    3 | ["color", "shape"]  |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### JSON_OBJECTAGG

```
mysql> SELECT o_id, attribute, value FROM t3;
+------+-----------+--------+
| o_id | attribute | value  |
+------+-----------+--------+
|    2 | color     | red    |
|    2 | fabric    | silk   |
|    3 | color     | green  |
|    3 | shape     | square |
+------+-----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT o_id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(attribute, value)
       FROM t3 GROUP BY o_id;
+------+---------------------------------------+
| o_id | JSON_OBJECTAGG(attribute, value)      |
+------+---------------------------------------+
|    2 | {"color": "red", "fabric": "silk"}    |
|    3 | {"color": "green", "shape": "square"} |
+------+---------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Those functions are also in MySQL 5.7.22. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg